# Can you provide translation to this Russian profanity?

Tags: словоупотребление, сленг, phrase, мат

I am familiar with the word **заебать** *[zə(j)ɪˈbatʲ]*, but I do not understand where does the word **как** come in picture. This surely doesn't change the meaning of the sentence, but a little explanation could be in place.

The way I'd figure out this is; the sentence **Да ты заебал** is translated 'Im sick of you/You sicken me/I'm tired of your shit'.

And logically, my guess here would be 'You really piss me off/You make me mad'. Is this close?

In comparison:

> Да ты заебал - You piss me off.
>
> Как ты меня заебал - You (really/truly) piss me off.

And yes, I do know and appreciate the speed limits in Russia. Let's take it easy.

Comment: It's "I'm sick of you/You sicken me/I'm tired of your sh**" + really: I'm really sick of you/I'm really tired of your sh**", etc.

Comment: So this only means that in English, the translation differs only by the word "really". I expected this, but does altering words with the abovementioned bad word "заеб*л" change the meaning in the ears of Russians?

What I'm looking for is possible difference to the ears of native Russian speakers.

Comment: "Как" here adds more "tiredness" like in "Как я устал".

Comment: The possible difference to the ears of native Russian speakers is this: the bad word has no bearing whatsoever on it. There is no reason at all for the example to be so extremely offensive. The only thing we are looking to translate is the *как*. The question can be changed to ask about translating "как ты надоел" instead, or "как я устал", or "как мне плохо". And it would still be the exact same question. The "bad word" as you call it can, and should, be plain removed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! I've edited the caption of your question because it contains an expletive. Question titles can be seen on the cross-site sidebar, so expletives are not welcome in the titles. Since we are a language-related site, expletives are OK in the body and tags and should be provided in their full uncensored form, as long they are the topic of the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Как` in this case can be literally translated into English as `how`, or maybe `Oh, how...`, used for emphasis, rather than a question.

> Как ты меня заебал! - Oh, how you've pissed me off!

This also works in other exclamations:

> Как я устал! - Oh, how tired I am!

Answer (score 1):

*Как* in this context means *so* in English.

Compare:

> I'm sick of you!
>
> I'm so sick of you!

And this sentence is quite rude, not sure the question will survive long enough.

Comment: It will survive. We don't delete questions here just because of rude words in russian phrases.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. For englishmen, the sentence has possibly more emphasis on their frustration, however rude the sentence is, no matter which way you put it.

And my point was not to upset anyone. As a student of Russian, I was merely interested in the core idea behind the choice of words. I wouldn't intend to use this anywhere. You've been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"I am sick of you" - is kinda mild translation for this because "заебал" is really rude in Russian. I'd choose something along these lines -

You are pissing me the fuck off!
You are fucking pissing me off!

(or "pissed off" depending on situation and context)

Comment: Yes, the true translation of the sentence would have to include bad words too, whatever the target language is.

This sentence is one of Russians bad word vocabulary, and often times the rules of grammar do not straightforwardly apply. However, I was curious whether native speakers themselves recognize difference between these two mentioned sentences, or are they just the **exact** same thing just with different words,

Comment: As it was mentioned above, "как" adds some additional feeling of being pissed off and tired. Like in "Как же я устал!", "Как мы долго едем, ужас.."

Answer (score 1):

The one thing the other answers do not mention is that "как" adds a flavor of impersonality to the expression. Here is what I mean: "да ты заебал" is directed towards the listener, while "как же ты меня заебал" is more of a general remark, if I you will. The first expression delivers information (in a rather crude way) to the person one's speaking with, while the second expression is more about reflecting on the fact that the person is pissing you off. So by using the second expression you're basically saying that communication with the person who's pissing you off is impossible and pointless.

For example, let's say you're in prison and you want to rest, but there is another prisoner in the cell who's trying to start a dialogue with you in a rather intrusive manner. Then the following conversation might take place:

```
-- Хочешь, я на одной ноге постою, как цапля?
-- Нет.
-- Нет, ну хочешь, я цаплей постою?
-- Да ты заебал! (= please, do stop it)
-- Ну давай я цаплей постою, хочешь?
-- Как же ты меня заебал!.. (= he's crazy, it's impossible to communicate with him)
```

Comment: -- Не хочешь?? Ну, тогда сейчас ты сам цаплей будешь стоять.